# Does Spring Kafka producer guarantee delivery by default?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I wonder whether `spring kafka` Producer within `spring boot` guarantee delivery or not.

Does anybody know what happens if some random listener fails to receive message? Would `spring kafka` retry to send the message?

Comment: Producer doesn't know anything about the consumers. And it has nothing to do with delivery. I just sends the message to the topic. Consumers subscribe to the topic and consume messages. It is a separate process.

Comment: Also, you can set the `retries` producer property. You can also wait for the future returned by the send operation to complete.

Answer (score 0):

There are some concepts here:

1. Producer will produce events and send them to kafka server. You must be aware on the producer side for retries and things like that if Kafka will have downtime or other error scenarios that are specific to your context.
2. Consumers will have assign partitions by Kafka, each partition will deliver events and each event will have an offset. Consumers will poll for data from kafka (they will request for data, kafka will not push data to consumers, but consumers will go to kafka and require data). Every event that is delivered with success by Kafka to the consumers will produce and Acknowledgment and Kafka will commit the offset of the event. So the next event, with a higher offeset will be delivered to the consumer. If a consumer goes down, partitions will be reasigned to other consumers, so you won't lose your data. If you have only one consumer, the data will be stored in Kafka and when the consumer will be back, it will go and request data from the latest/earliest offset.